# Denied entry to UK in 2009, can I apply for a student visa in 2019?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, indian-citizens, denied-entry

I was denied entry into a UK airport when I was a student in UK in 2009. My college then was not on the list of providers, and I had admitted to UKVI after they pressed me that I had not attended college since my last visa application for leave to remain in UK. The immigration officer said I had used deception in my last application for leave to remain.

I was removed at port at UK airport and my residence permit retained. That was in 2009. Now in 2019 I wish to make a tier 4 visa application from India.

This time in 2019 I have received an unconditional offer in MSc mechanical engineering from a top 3 UK university. So apart from the negative feedback can anyone give me a ray of hope? Also what can I say about my historic old denial at port in 2009?

Comment: Please edit your original question to include all the extra information you provided in comments on that question and in your new question. Possible duplicate of [old entry denial](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141604/old-entry-denial)

Comment: I am going to move this question to Expatriates, as the one with more information. But you can still edit both questions with more information (you will need to make an account on Expats if you do not have one yet.)

Comment: Can you afford to consult a UK immigration lawyer? An engineering master's degree from a good university will be worth hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of dollars over your career.

Comment: patricia last year i spent 2500 GBP on a lawyer to remove an incorrect ban. All this was for a single letter of representation which i could have done on my own. So i just need to prepare a letter addressing that old entry denial. Any suggestions patricia? Also patricia , there is a question on the application form which says" have i ever been denied entry to UK in last 10 years, if i apply next month i will answer""Yes"", but if i apply next year i can answer ""No"' , so please guide me

Comment: @lindisingh If the online application is the same as this version https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/752361/vaf-2-11-18.pdf, unlike the other questions on travel history, the question about visa refusals/denial of entry etc is not limited to the last 10 years. It asks if you have EVER (emphasis added) been refused entry etc.’.

Comment: yes traveller i get your point, that means the form has changed, and then i guess it wont make a difference applying this year or next isn't it?

Comment: I have given you my best advice - get a lawyer. Spending a few thousand dollars to get this right would be a good investment, given your potential lifetime earnings gain if you can take up the MSc offer.

Comment: okay patricia, i will treasure your advice, and act on it, one last thing, in a tier 4 application i will be subject to a credibility interveiw, in that i have to answer their questions, in that  a lawyer cannot help me, as in lot of cases the ukvi reject people from high risk countries like mine on credibility interveiws on statements like my future lans, source of income, anything they like, but still i will heed your advice

Comment: I don't know enough to offer an answer but I would not be optimistic. A work visa would be a challenge but another student visa? Have you been a student for 10 years? Resuming your studies after working for some time? With your age and history, it's bound to look like you are looking for a pretext to reenter the UK. And if you are as nervous about all this as you tell us in your question, your demeanor in the interview is unlikely to bolster your credibility.